# I have ASP.NET GridView in my web app and would like to bind 3 columns with values based on one column

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have ASP.NET GridView in my web app and would like to bind 3 columns with values based on one column. I am providing example below, is it possible to implement into GridView?

My Gridview fields are

```
Name|Score1|Score2|Score3
```

I will display the name but how to fill the score fields based on name.there are 3 scores corresponding to each name,that we taken from the same table with a single score field.the 3 scores are provided by 3 different persons.Also i want to display the corresponding score providers name in the header portion of the gridview.

ie,

```
Name|Ram Score1|Raju Score2|Mohan Score3
```

How can i do this...

Plz provide the query to do this

Comment: What you tried ? Post your code

Comment: @Monica you need to give more detail then this

Answer (score 0):

Consider to rather calculate the scoring fields in database. Create a stored procedure and bind it to the grid view.